# Is it possible to monitor notifications?

Tags: application-development

I would like to programmatically monitor the notifications that get displayed in Ubuntu (in order to perform different actions based on the content of the notifications). I do not see a feature that offers this sort of ability documented anywhere in notify-osd. Can anyone recommend a method for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2):

In theory at least, you can find all notifications in the file

```
$HOME/.cache/notify-osd.log
```

However, I no longer find that file in 12.04.

There is an applet called "recent notifications", and you can install it by adding a PPA repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jconti/recent-notifications
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-notifications
```

Maybe that will help.

Comment: The notify-osd.log file _would_ fit my needs perfectly, but since it doesn't exist in 12.04 (I can't find it in my installation either) that isn't going to work for me. Is it possible that the file is missing because of a bug?

Comment: Quick google tells me that users complained about that file waking up their hard drives.